Inline struct initialization, "nonstatic member must be relative to a static object"
I have a small issue with referencing the outer struct members from a nested struct. When I try to set x and y to width and height it shows the error "a nonstatic member must be relative to a static object", here is the code:
const int width = 1280, height = 720;
struct MandelbrotBase
{
    int width = ::width, height = ::height;
    ...
    struct
    {
        int x = width / 2;
        int y = height / 2;
    } pos;
} mb;
__global__ void generate_mandelbrot(unsigned int* colors, MandelbrotBase mb)
{
...
}

Is not that a big problem, since I can reference the global ::width and ::heigth instead, or other methods to initialize. But, is there any possibility to do do it just inline? Using a member constructor or function is not an option, at least is not a preferred option, because I use it to pass information to cuda kernel functions, so I want to keep it very simple.

What do you mean by "But, is there any possibility to do do it just inline?"?  Can you give an example of what you are looking to achieve?

@NathanOliver Just inline is how it is shown in the sample of code provided, see x and y, initialized online, trying to refer the outer struct members width and height. I want exactly that, if there exist some syntax to make it possible.

this would be a problem in C++ as well.  Not unique to CUDA.

You can make it like
const int width = 1280, height = 720;

struct MandelbrotBase {
  int width = ::width, height = ::height;
  struct {
    int x;
    int y;
  } pos = {.x = width / 2, .y = height / 2};
} mb;

void generate_mandelbrot(unsigned int* colors, MandelbrotBase mb) {}

Non static width and height can't be referenced outside MandelbrotBase members without an object. The unnamed struct is not a part of the struct MandelbrotBase definition, the unnamed struct is just defined in the struct MandelbrotBase name scope.

Thanks, nice. It worked like this pos = { width / 2, height / 2}

Small correction static constexpr int width = 1280;
